# What benefit is there in wrapping a simple type in a class?

Tags: c#

I am looking at code that is essentially passing an id around, for example:

```
GetPersonById(int personId)
```

But instead of using an int, it used a PersonId object.

```
GetPersonById(PersonId personId)
```

The PersonId object is just an int with some hand-cranked code to make it nullable. So was this created in old .NET when nullable ints weren't available or is there a higher purpose for wrapping simple types in a class?

```
public sealed class PersonId {

    private PersonId() {
        _isNull = true;
        _value = 0;
    }


    private PersonId(int value) {
        _isNull = false;
        _value = value;
    }

    // and so on!
}
```

Comment: One reason I would image is keeping track of the objects life cycle. Maybe automate some ID release mechanism?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I can't really describe the code in great detail and have yet to fathom the thoughts of the creator, but on the whole I would say that the domain was far from their thoughts. I'd like to hear how this would be used in DDD though, rather than an int (or a Person class).

Comment: @mtsvetkov - can you elaborate in an answer please?

Comment: @Sohnee: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12250401/572644) for an explanation

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) code like this is used to make the type this ID references more explicit.

Especially in the context of well designed aggregates, references to other aggregates are very often by ID, not by object reference. In this case, those ID value objects can be used to avoid accidential mixing of these IDs and - as said before - to make it more explicit what aggregate is being referenced.

Comment: +1 The private constructors of the `PersonId` make it likely to have more meaning than "just a nullable value".

Comment: Right - so if we took out the manually created nullable code and used a nullable int (and adjusted the methods accordingly) it could still have value - you could never pass a `PersonId` into `GetSession(SessionId sessionId)` for example.

Answer (score 8):

Using a class is a nice way to simplify further refactoring if the fields used to identify a person need to change. Suppose tomorrow the system reaches `Int32.MaxValue` people and you want to use an `Int64` or a string to identify them. Another case would be, when the requirements for the system are not 100% accurate, and they didn't specify if a person would be identified by an ID, a PIN, or whatever combination of fields that you can think of. The author of this code, might have though of preventing a major refactoring by creating this class.

Answer (score 5):

The answer could be the semantics as well!

Imagine that you have some `int` value. Is it an `ID`? Or is it age, height in cm, temperature in centigrade, number of TV program? Well, you can give a good name to the variable, but this won't protect you if you make a mistake.

On the contrary, if a function requires an ID class instance (which is, well, `int` in disguise) and not just `int`, but you are trying to pass X-coordinate value by mistake (which happens to be `int` as well, or instance of `Coordinate`, or whatever), compiler *will* catch it and warn you. And besides that, anyone reading the code can clearly see that the needed value is not *just* int, but an ID -- you cannot do it better with documentation, noone reads it anyway.

(Side note: you cannot imagine, how much headache I had trying to refactor the code which used `double` for the angles in both degrees and radians! It was a nightmare! After switching to a `class Angle`, everything went much better.)

Answer (score 2):

This code was probably written in C# 1.0 when `Nullable<T>` didn't exist.

Now you should use `int?` instead.

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions that fast. There might be other reasons. I have seen this kind of value object in a lot of DDD code and samples.

Comment: I supposed this to be the case in the question. I can't think of any reason to do this other than it being created prior to nullable ints, so unless anyone comes up with a compelling reason, you'll get the green tick!

Comment: I don't believe in `-1` but please don't use words like `Obviously` when you don't know what you are talking about. Thanks (-`

Comment: @JakubKonecki - `+1` for that (;

Answer (score 1):

For me I think it is preferable to use the most primitive types of the framework.

-> No benefits

Answer (score 1):

The old C# can be a one explanation for it.
but I would guess it can have other explanation, a future thinking...
If in the future you would like to have more data for a person, by changing the PersonId class itself or by inherit it, all the code will still work fine as is. but if you would use `int?` then you will have to change all the calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit, except using value types as nullable. Nothing more.